# Invalid column name when using a COALESCE field with Row_Number()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query which works fine with SQL Server 2008:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName] 
 FROM Emp_General 
 ORDER BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

(Notice that it is ordering by the CalculatedEmployeeName field and not complaining)

When I add a Row_Number field as follows:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName]
 , Row_Number() Over (Order BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC) RecordNumber
 FROM Emp_General
 ORDER BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

I get an error of:

```
Invalid column name 'CalculatedEmployeeName'.
```

Any ideas on why it is complaining?

Note that I have already tried using

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
```

and

```
row_number() over (order by @@rowcount)
```

as discussed in:

[SQL Row_Number() function in Where Clause without ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390224/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause-without-order-by?lq=1)

But they do not return the row_number in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 ;with cte as
    (
    SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName]
     FROM Emp_General
    )

    select *,Row_Number() Over (Order BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC)  as RecordNumber from cte ORDER BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

Comment: This accomplished what I needed.  This way, I can have several other fields in the original select statement and create a Row_number based on any number of them being sorted in any way.  Then in the final select, all I have to do is sort on the calculated row_number field.  ALSO (and why i needed it.)  It allows me to do paging based on arbitrary sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName]
     , Row_Number() Over (Order BY COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) ASC) RecordNumber
FROM Emp_General
ORDER BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

Cannot reference derived columns in the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the name you specified in this query, you have to use the full name:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName)  [CalculatedEmployeeName], 
Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) ASC) RecordNumber
FROM Emp_General
```

Or, alternatively, you can use something like:

```
;with Data as (
    SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName] 
    FROM Emp_General 

) SELECT CalculatedEmployeeName, Row_Number() 
      OVER(Order By CalculatedEmployeeName Asc) RecordNumber FROM Data 
ORDER BY [CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

Comment: using the full name gets an Incorrect syntax near 'Row_Number'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery to access derived column

```
SELECT Z.[CalculatedEmployeeName],
       Row_Number() Over (Order BY Z.[CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC) RecordNumber
FROM 
(
 SELECT COALESCE(LastName + ', ' + FirstName, LastName, FirstName) [CalculatedEmployeeName] 
 FROM Emp_General 
) Z
 ORDER BY Z.[CalculatedEmployeeName] ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that ORDER BY is the last in the order of the computation of the SQL server.
SQL order of operations is:
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause

(data from here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm)

So SQL can order by this computed column, but it cannot do ROW_NUMBER on it.
As suggested above, you can either use cte or write explicitly the calculation.